# Problem with Actionscript Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I have to parse out color information from HTML data.  The colors can either be RGB colors or file names to a swatch image.

I used http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ to develop and test the patterns.  I copied the AS regular expression code verbatim from the tool into Flex Builder.  But, when I exec the pattern against the string I get a null.

Here are the patterns and an example of the string (I took the correct HTML tags out so the strings would show correctly):

DIV data:

```
<div style="background-color:rgb(2,2,2);width:10px;height:10px;">
```

DIV pattern:

```
/([0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3})/
```

IMG data:

```
<img src="/media/swatches/jerzeesbirch.gif" width="10" height="10" alt="Birch">
```

IMG pattern:

```
/[a-z0-9_-]+/[a-z0-9_-]+/[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+/
```

Here's my Actionscript code:

```
var divPattern : RegExp = new RegExp("/([0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3})/");
var imgPattern : RegExp = new RegExp("/[a-z0-9_-]+/[a-z0-9_-]+/[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+/");

var divResult : Array = divPattern.exec(object.swatch);
var imgResult : Array = imgPattern.exec(object.swatch);
```

Both of the arrays are null.

This is my first foray into AS coding, so I think I'm declaring something wrong.

Steve

Comment: I assume you've checked that trace(object.swatch); returns a valid string?

Comment: +1 for http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I don't know ActionScript but I know Javascript and they should be close enough to solve your problem.)

---

To construct a RegExp object for e.g. the pattern `^[a-z]+$`, you either use

```
var pattern : RegExp = new RegExp("^[a-z]+$");
```

or, better,

```
var pattern : RegExp = /^[a-z]+$/
```

The code `new RegExp("/^[a-z]+$/")` is wrong because this expects a slash before the `^` and after the `$`.

---

Therefore, your DIV pattern should be written as

```
var divPattern : RegExp = /([0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3})/;
```

but, as you know, the `(` and `)` are special characters for capturing, you need to escape them:

```
var divPattern : RegExp = /\([0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3}\)/;
```

---

For the IMG pattern, as `/` delimitates a RegEx, you need to escape it as well:

```
var imgPattern : RegExp = /[a-z0-9_-]+\/[a-z0-9_-]+\/[a-z0-9_-]+\.[a-z0-9_-]+/
```

---

Finally, you could use `\d` in place of `[0-9]` and `\w` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough to tell if your regex patterns are correct, but from the docs on the [AS3 RegExp class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e92.html), it looks like your `new RegExp()` call needs a second argument to declare flags for case sensitivity etc.

EDIT: Also, as [Bart K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50476/bart-k) has pointed out, you don't need the / delimiters when using the `new` method.

So you can use either:

```
var divPattern:RegExp = new RegExp("([0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3})", "");
```

OR you can also use the alternate syntax with /:

```
var divPattern:RegExp = /([0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3},[0-9]{1,3})/;
```

... in which case the flag string (if any) is included after the final /

Comment: No, when using new `new RegExp(...)` no delimiters are needed (see the link you posted).

Comment: You can omit the () delimiters, but if you DO use them you I think you need to supply a second argument (even if it's an empty string as shown in Adobe's example). And spdaly's code uses the delimiters.

Comment: No, I was talking about the `/` delimiters. Instantiating a RegExp  is done by doing either `var pattern:RegExp = /\w/;` or `var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp("\w");`. The `new RegExp(...` syntax expects a plain string (without the delimiters!). See: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=12_Using_Regular_Expressions_04.html#119163

Comment: Aahh - see what you mean now, thanks for pointing that out. I will update my answer.